# How to build a Dynamic Tabbar and Tabview using Flutter and GetX by calling API

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am new to Flutter and GETX...

My requirement is to get tab names from API...  than get tab data from API, based on every tab selection...

I found getx usage in tabview [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969768/how-to-change-screen-using-flutter-getx), but I don't know how to make it to work with API response. I tried to achieve this by adding api call in *`onInit`* method in my `controller` class but have no luck with it....

**Here is my controller....**

```
class MyTabController extends GetxController with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var tabNames= List<TabNameModel>().obs;
  List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[].obs;

  TabController controller;

 void fetchApiData() async {
    isLoading(true);
    try {
      var response = await <HTTP API Call>;
      
      tabNames
          .assignAll(response != null ? tabNamesFromJson(response) : null);
      for (TabNameModel tabname in TabNameModel.value) {
        myTabs.add(Tab(text: tabname.name));
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }


  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchApiData()
    super.onInit();
    controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

some times I get empty tabs and some time I get error like this....
[image: error screen]

**Here is my screen......**

```
class MyTabbedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MyTabController _tabx = Get.put(MyTabController());
    // ↑ init tab controller

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    bottom: TabBar(
      controller: _tabx.controller,
      tabs: _tabx.myTabs,
    ),
  ),
  body: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabx.controller,
    children: _tabx.myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
      final String label = tab.text.toLowerCase();
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          'This is the $label tab',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

`MyTabbedWidget` is trying to use `myTabs` from the Controller before `fetchApiData` async call has finished populating `myTabs`. `myTabs` is empty until fetch call completes.

`TabBarView` will try to access `myTabs` which will be zero-length until API call finishes.  Flutter TabController length cannot be zero, or it will throw an error, which I think you are seeing.

## Solutions

**Two solutions: Blocking & Non-Blocking**

#### Blocking Solution

One solution is to make the `fetchApiData` async call ***prior*** to the application start and wait for it to finish before proceeding.  Done in a Bindings class.  This will delay the loading of the page until the call finishes.  If this is OK, this would be a potential solution:

```
// make main ↓ async
void main() async {
  await MyBlockingBindings().dependencies();
  // ↑ make API call prior to app start, wait for results
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyBlockingBindings extends Bindings {
  List<Tab> loadedTabs = [];

  @override
  Future<void> dependencies() async {
    // ↓ long-duration async call to load tab data
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2),
            () => loadedTabs = [
              Tab(text: 'BlockedLeft'),
              Tab(text: 'BlockedRight')
            ]
    );

    // ↓ Register controller using fetched tab data
    Get.put(MyTabController(myTabs: loadedTabs));
  }
}

class MyTabController extends GetxController with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
  List<Tab> myTabs;

  // ↓ Constructor can now take myTabs argument
  MyTabController({this.myTabs});

  TabController controller;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

Since we did `Get.put(MyTabController())` in `MyBlockingBindings` we can use `Get.find()` in our view widget.

```
class MyTabbedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MyTabController _tabx = Get.find();
    // ↑ controller already init in Bindings, just find it

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabx.controller,
          tabs: _tabx.myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabx.controller,
        children: _tabx.myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          final String label = tab.text.toLowerCase();
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'This is the $label tab',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The rest is unchanged from [the example you followed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014702/2301224).

#### Non-Blocking Solution

This solution loads immediately with placeholder tab data, then swaps placeholder data with tabs loaded from API call, after they've arrived.

The (fake) 2 sec. API call `asyncLoadTabs()` is done in `MyTabController` `onInit()`.  Note that we're not using `await` here and `onInit` is not made `async`.  We don't want to block processing. The async call will run when Flutter's event loop gets around to it.

In `MyTabbedWidget` we wrap everything in a `GetBuilder<MyTabController>` widget.  When we call `update()` in `MyTabController` our GetBuilder will rebuild itself using the latest data.

#### API Calls on Tab Switch

`TabBar onTap:` calls controller's `switchTab(index)` which in turn calls `asyncLoadTabs` with the index of the tab selected, making another API call with the tab #.

```
void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyTabController extends GetxController with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
  List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'loading...'),
  ];

  // ↓ Constructor can now take myTabs argument
  MyTabController({myTabs}) {
    this.myTabs ??= myTabs;
  }

  TabController controller;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
    asyncLoadTabs();
  }

  // Fake 2 sec. async call
  void asyncLoadTabs({int index = 0}) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      myTabs = [
        Tab(text: 'LEFT $index'),
        Tab(text: 'RIGHT $index'),
      ];
      controller.dispose(); // release animation resources
      // recreate TabController as length is final/cannot change ↓
      controller = TabController(
          vsync: this,
          length: myTabs.length,
          initialIndex: index // to show a particular tab on create
      );
      update();
      // ↑ rebuilds GetBuilder widget with latest controller data
    });
  }

  void switchTab(int index) async {
    asyncLoadTabs(index: index);
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
}

class MyTabbedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // ↓ use GetBuilder & rebuild using update()
    return GetBuilder<MyTabController>(
      init: MyTabController(),
      builder: (_tabx) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabx.controller,
            tabs: _tabx.myTabs,
            onTap: _tabx.switchTab, // receives tab # on tab click
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabx.controller,
          children: _tabx.myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
            final String label = tab.text.toLowerCase();
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                'This is the $label tab',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you feed TabBarView from API call on each tab selection ???

Comment: Updated with TabBar onTap handler to make API calls on tab selection to update tabs.

Comment: Just Curious.... instead of using GetBuilder.., how do I achieve it with Obx...?

Answer (score -1):

Here's my Code, From my API I had all the categories and foods nested inside the categories.
Api Response

```
{
  "data": {
    "getOneRestaurant": {
      "error": false,
      "msg": "Restaurant Get Successfully",
      "data": {
        "cover_img": "https://i.ibb.co/YNZ64QG/0-89399200-1551782137-fast1.jpg",
        "description": "",
        "address": {
          "address": "21 KDA Approach Rd, Khulna 9200, Bangladesh"
        },
        "food_categories": [
          {
            "_id": "5fa122713cf61557a65d0a12",
            "name": "Fast Food",
            "foods": [
              {
                "_id": "5fcc709678070b0098203a0f",
                "name": "Chicken reshmi kabab",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/kHGcn3v/Indian-chicken-kebab-Getty-Images-91279048-58eee4623df78cd3fcd0c6ca.jpg",
                "price": 320,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fcc719178070b0098203a10",
                "name": "Kacchi biriyani",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/Zmp3yp5/47125153f54b972670697f49dac933cc.jpg",
                "price": 230,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fcc722578070b0098203a11",
                "name": "Chicken tikka ",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/M2sLTqP/img-20161210-221320-largejpg.jpg",
                "price": 170,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fcc72f478070b0098203a12",
                "name": "Chicken tandoori 1 pcs",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/LZw5Fp2/chicken-tandori-1526595014.jpg",
                "price": 170,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce042d78070b0098203b1b",
                "name": "Special thai soup for 4 person",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/YtmVwmm/download.jpg",
                "price": 300,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce048b78070b0098203b1c",
                "name": "Thai clear soup for 4 person",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/BjcRvNL/tomyum800-56a9498e5f9b58b7d0f9ea4f.jpg",
                "price": 250,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce04d078070b0098203b1d",
                "name": "Chicken vegetables soup four 4 person",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/ZN3Bxnk/chicken-vegetable-soup-9-1200.jpg",
                "price": 180,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce050678070b0098203b1e",
                "name": "Russian salad",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/vxh9qGZ/download.jpg",
                "price": 200,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce053378070b0098203b1f",
                "name": "Green salad",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/XpwwB8Y/green-salad-1200-1387.jpg",
                "price": 100,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce056878070b0098203b20",
                "name": "French fries",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/NCPsK6Y/Copycat-Mc-Donalds-French-Fries-500x500.jpg",
                "price": 60,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce059a78070b0098203b21",
                "name": "Chicken fry  4 pic",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/9hwPhgd/download-1.jpg",
                "price": 180,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce05dc78070b0098203b22",
                "name": "Chicken burger",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/HnJH38T/Butchies-2.jpg",
                "price": 80,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce060078070b0098203b23",
                "name": "Chicken pizza ",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/WWXzqdk/download.jpg",
                "price": 120,
                "price_and_size": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5fce062a78070b0098203b24",
                "name": "Chicken naan",
                "description": "",
                "dish_img": "https://i.ibb.co/cgLg923/download-1.jpg",
                "price": 60,
                "price_and_size": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tab's

```
TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 20),
        controller: _tabController,
        labelColor: Color(0xffC8102E),
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),
        unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
        ),
        indicatorColor: Color(0xffC8102E),
        tabs: profile.foodCategories.map((e) => Tab(text: e.name)).toList(),
      )
```

Body

```
TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController,
      children: profile.foodCategories.map((RestaurantFoodCategories e) {
        return itemList(e.foods, e.id);
      }).toList(),
    )
```

ItemList

```
  Widget itemList(List<RestaurantFoods> items,String id) {
    return ListView.builder(
      primary: false,
      itemCount: items.length ?? 0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        RestaurantFoods item  = items[index];
        return itemCard(item, id);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: How the controller defined??

Comment: When the API call is done and I have the data I initialize controller then. 
_tabController = TabController(length: profile.foodCategories.length, vsync: this)